# What kind of sins would determine if a Prinny is sent to the Netherworld or Celestia?

Tags: disgaea

In Disgaea, humans who have sinned become Prinnies, and they either go to the Netherworld or Celestia. In Celestia, they work as maids and domestic servants where their good deeds go towards their redemption. However, in the Netherworld, they have to earn Hel to be redeemed and seemed to be treated far more harshly (probably because their masters are selfish demons like Etna or Laharl).

For Laharl's mother, she committed the sin of taking her own life. However, she did it only to cure him, yet she was made into a Prinny of the Netherworld despite the good intentions.

I am wondering what kind of sins would determine if a Prinny is sent to the Netherworld or Celestia, and if the reason behind committing such sin plays a role in it.

Comment: Laharl's mother might have been a special case; according to [Disgaea wiki](http://disgaea.wikia.com/wiki/Big_Sis_Prinny), her prayers were heard before she died, allowing her daughter to be born in Celestia. It's possible she was also able to get herself turned into a Netherworld Prinny so she could keep watching over Laharl. I don't have any evidence, so not an answer.

Comment: @Torisuda i haven't played Disgaea D2 yet so i didn't know Laharl's sister was from Celestia (ofcause would explain how it gets involved again in Laharl's life again) but if Laharl's mother was carrying his sister at the time of her death then that could have been seen as murder rather that suicide and i know murdered get sent to the Nether world

Comment: That's also possible. My knowledge is pretty much limited to Disgaea 1 and a bit of 2. I haven't played D2 either since I don't have a PS3. All I can really remember from Disgaea 1 about the Prinnies' sins is Etna saying at some point that Netherworld Prinnies were bad people like thieves and murderers when they were alive.